# Highcharts: Render the bar chart from the bottom

Tags: highcharts

I want to render a bar chart using highchart. It automatically starts to plot the bars from the center. How should i make the bars to start immediately from the bottom?

This is my portion of the code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [ 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                fillOpacity: 0.1
            }
        },

        series: [{

         pointWidth: 15,
            data: [ 54.4]
        }]
    });
```

I expect the bars should start from the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pointPlacement` property:

```
series: [{
    pointPlacement: -0.475,
    pointWidth: 15,
    data: [54.4]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2wht3yf4/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.pointPlacement